# Define React Router Routes In Another Components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom 5.2.0.
I want 2 files that define all of my routes. 1 file for public routes, 1 file for private.
The right component renders when I hit the home route, but not the /content route.

App.jsx returns:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <PublicRoutes />
    <PrivateRoutes />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

PublicRoutes.jsx returns:

```
<Route path="/" exact render={() => <h1>home route</h1>} />
```

And PrivateRoutes.jsx returns:

```
<Route path="/content" exact render={() => <h1>Content Route</h1>} />
```

I am able to load / with "home route", but nothing renders when I hit the /content url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those Switches need to go **inside** your wrapper routes, like so:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const PublicRoutes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact render={() => <h1>home route</h1>} />
  </Switch>
);
const PrivateRoutes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/content" exact>
      <h1>Content Route</h1>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <PublicRoutes />
      <PrivateRoutes />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-river-ysv4w?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

The `Switch` component returns and renders the first matching `Route` or `Redirect` component. `PublicRoutes` nor `PrivateRoutes` are neither, the `PublicRoutes` is returned by default.

[Switch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)

> Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the
> location.

## Solution

You'll need to render a `Route` in the `Switch` that checks the authentication condition and conditionally render one or the other.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route
      render={(routeProps) => authCondition ? (
        <PublicRoutes {...routeProps} />
      ) : (
        <PrivateRoutes {...routeProps} />
      )}
    />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

If your public and private routes are split on the path then you can likely more simply render each on their perspective paths.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/content" component={PrivateRoutes} />
    <Route path="/" component={PublicRoutes} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

With either you will then likely need to render a nested `Switch` that builds on the base path of each if you've further nested routes.

Answer (score 0):

in react router v6 it is possible by using `outlet` base on [docs](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#nested-routes-and-layouts)

or you should use this

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="dashboard/*" element={<Dashboard />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Look, more routes!</p>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<DashboardGraphs />} />
        <Route path="invoices" element={<InvoiceList />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

please Pay attention to * end of `path="dashboard/*"`